# Downvotes, downvotes for all!

Tags: discussion, down-votes

It is strange that **every** good answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146417/if-n-is-an-odd-natural-number-then-8-divides-n2-1/146425#146425) has exactly two downvotes each. Would it be sensible to revert this, or should we not care?

Comment: Your reputation reminds me of the internet when I first started using it, 16 years ago. I had state of the art 28.8k modem... *sigh* Good times!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Revert what to what?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Make the downvotes disappear.

Comment: [If you worry too much about voting patterns on this site, you will lose your sleep.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1722/49437)

Comment: Heh, now this got downvoted.

Comment: @Jyrki: I don't think that's right. I think he would downvote more often. The upvotes, I believe went mostly to the questions... (Also I doubt he's really gone.)

Comment: Bill still reads main and meta, but I don't know why we are still talking about him (or sticking to coy pronouns).

Answer (score 18):

There's nothing moderators can do about this, the information they can access about votes is not fine-grained enough to see if anything strange is going on here.

I would generally not worry too much about small patterns of potentially bad votes, in the grand scheme of things a few votes have almost no effect. But if you stumble upon a larger abusive pattern of votes, just flag one affected post and explain what you observed.

Even though I previously said that moderators can't see or do anything about this specific situation, they can still ask SE to investigate and intervene. I don't think this is necessary in such a small case, but the option exists if someone is trying to abuse the voting system in a large fashion.